# Using a specific nadgrid with Openlayers 6 / Proj4js

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, proj4js

I have an issue with reprojecting vector data from one coordinate system to another by using proj4js.

The data source uses a Gauss Kruger 2 Projection ([EPSG: 31466](https://epsg.io/31466)) and I want to convert it to **EPSG:3857** and display it.
Generally it's working fine, but there is a small offset (maybe ~ 1-2 meters) compared to a WMS Service that is displaying areal photos in the background.

Adding these layers in QGIS3 has the same output, but there I can switch the datum-transformation of the vector layer from

```
+towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7
```

to

```
+nadgrids=BETA2007.gsb
```

and the output looks as expected. [DE_DHDN (BeTA, 2007) nach ETRS89](http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/descrtrans/BeTA/de_dhdn2etrs_beta.php)

But unfortunatly I'm failing at using / embedding this grid with proj4/ol. Is there any way to use it with these frameworks or an example with a similar approach (i.e. with other coordinate systems)? My googling skills have come to an end. :)

Funfacts:

- Angular 9.1.4
- Openlayers 6.3.1
- Proj4 2.6.2
- Reprojecting from an [EPSG:25832](https://epsg.io/25832) source works perfectly

tl;dr:
Is it possible to use a specific nadgrid in Openlayers/Proj4js?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proj4js does support grid transforms in recent versions.

To use +nadgrids= in a proj definition, first read your NTv2 .gsb file (e.g. from https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid) into an ArrayBuffer, then pass it to proj4.nadgrid. E.g:

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync('ntv2.gsb').buffer
proj4.nadgrid('key', buffer);
```

Then use the given key in your proj4 definition string, e.g.

```
+nadgrids=@key,null
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4#grid-based-datum-adjustments.

Comment: Is this still valid ? I see in your tests that you load grid shifts

Comment: I just updated the answer. proj4 can now do grid shift transforms.